# In-place quick-sort using random partition and only the array as argument

Tags: java, quicksort, in-place

I need to implement a quick-sort in java, when the following partition method is given:

```
private static int partition (int[] A, int low, int high)
{
int pivot, tmp, l, r;
pivot = low + qsr.nextInt(high - low + 1);
l = low;
r = high-1;
tmp = A[pivot];
A[pivot] = A[high];
A[high] = tmp;
pivot = high;
do
    {
    tmp = A[l];
    A[l] = A[r];
    A[r] = tmp;
    for(; l <= r && A[l] < A[pivot]; ++l)
        ;
    for(; l <= r && A[pivot] < A[r]; --r)
        ;
    }
while (l <= r);
tmp = A[l];
A[l] = A[pivot];
A[pivot] = tmp;
return l;
}
```

It chooses a random element from the array between the low and high index as pivot. Then the left side of the pivot is sorted so that it contains smaller values than the pivot, and the right side so that it contains only larger values. The sorting is done between the low and high values only. Finally, the index of the pivot is returned.

The quick-sort would be very easy to implement if the function took the low and high values as argument, but it doesn't:

```
 public static int[] quickSort (int[] table)
{return table;}
```

So it's a bit hairy problem. As I see it, I either have to create an array which stores the indexes or somehow split the array in place (not sure if possible), and then call the function recursively.

Any ideas how the algorithm can be created?

Comment: What's wrong with `public static int[] quickSort (int[] table) { return quickSortHelper(table, 0, table.length); }` where all the recursion is done in `quickSortHelper`?

Comment: @JimGarrison This is an exercise so that would be considered cheating, the partitioning method should be used.

Comment: Actually no, that is how recursive partitioning algorithms are structured.  The "front end" visible to the user is a thin shell that initiates the top of the recursive stack of partitioning method calls.

Comment: @JimGarrison At least it works now, here was the code I used for the recursion: `int a;
  if (low >= high)

   return tab;

  a=partition(tab,low,high);
  quickSortHelper(tab,low,a-1);
  quickSortHelper(tab,a+1,high);


  return tab;`

Comment: Actually both methods could be called `quickSort` since they have different parameter lists.